# jquery click function not working for me

Tags: php, jquery, function, fadein, fadeout

[The source code of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf15d.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAgv.png)

I want to be able to click on a thumbnail and the get a modal screen with the image. i used php to set the id and class names but it stil isnt working. i looked everywhere to find a solution but cant find any i have tryed this: [Why is this jQuery click function not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602331/why-is-this-jquery-click-function-not-working). but also this doesnt work the problem isnt with javascript ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

the first 2 querys work when i want to fadeIn the image and the fadeOut when pressed ESC but the last one when i click on my overlay it isnt working please help me.

The one with the red circle isnt working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error in the code:

```
$('#63848').on('click', '#63848', function() {
```

this syntax means you are looking fon an element (second selector) inside a parent container (the first one selector). So you can change the parent container to `'body'` or what else you want, like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#63848', function(event) {
```

or just remove the container

```
$('#63848').on('click', function(event) {
```

see a working example here of your scenario: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kcu0tr0f/1/)

Comment: Even when i put 
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
in it, it still isn't working. But isn't it kinda weird that the other 2 work and only the last one doesn't?

Comment: event.preventDefault();* 
event.stopPropagation();*

Comment: @NankoPrinzhorn i added a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kcu0tr0f/1/ . if you're still having issues try reproducing it inside a fiddle so we can help you

Comment: OKEE it works now..... What i did was making a new class in the div and called when i click on that class go fadeOut and that works....