# Enable/Disable Delete Button with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with Enabling a button with a checkbox using JavaScript. Whenever I click the checkbox, the Delete button stays disabled.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#cb_delete').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
         $('#btn-delete').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('#btn-delete').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

</script>

<button type='submit' name='btn-delete' disabled='disabled' id='btn-delete' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>Delete</button> 
<td><input type='checkbox' name='cb_delete[]' id='cb_delete' value='$mID'></td>
```

Comment: You could replace everything inside the event handler with just `$('#btn-delete').prop('disabled', this.checked)`

Comment: 99% if the time if you see `attr` you really need `prop`.  The confusion tends to come from early version of jQuery which mixed both behaviors under the same `attr` method.

Comment: Also, if your script tag appears before your `#cb_delete` element is in the DOM, it won't attach the event because it won't find the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this jQuery click function not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602331/why-is-this-jquery-click-function-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```js
$('#cb_delete').change(function() {
  $('#btn-delete').prop('disabled', !($(this).is(":checked")));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' name='btn-delete' disabled='disabled' id='btn-delete' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>Delete</button>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='cb_delete[]' id='cb_delete' value='$mID'>
  <br>OTHERS1:
  <input type='checkbox' name='others1[]' id='other1' value='$oID'>
  <br>OTHERS2:
  <input type='checkbox' name='others2[]' id='other2' value='$iID'>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does work for me, however as I have put the in click event inside the checkbox, if there are multiple checkboxs, it toggles everytime I click a different checkbox

Comment: @James Since only one checkbox has id `cb_delete`, i dont think it should be an issue

Comment: @James just updated. I added dummy checkboxes. Note that they don't enable or disable the button.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying, I understand the concept now. This works perfectly for me, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The way you are checking to see if the box is checked or not is not a good way of doing it.  Try:

```
if( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {

}else{

}
```