# jquery call is not being done

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery call is not being done:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#links').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
    </script>
<a id="links" href="http://www.amazon.com" >Amazon</a>
```

EDIT:

Also not working with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We don't like to add it `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` because jquery versions may not be updated in this file but all code works if we add this.

The above code also not getting desired result if we add it inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#links').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you requiring jQuery? You're listing jQuery-UI

Comment: Added jquery here as earlier missed

Comment: I recommend `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Your problem is highlighted here https://jsfiddle.net/s6e8rjL0/ - try changing in the *JAVASCRIPT* setting from `LOAD TYPE` - `No wrap - in <head>` to `No wrap - in <body>` and your script works. It is as simple as ensuring your content is loaded before the script runs.

Comment: @Jonathan would you answer it with detail

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam would have answered with community wiki as this is a very common question on SO. Have a look at that fiddle. Inspect the HTML quadrant and find the `<iframe>`. Then look at the difference between the in-head and in-body load type. With your script in the head, you can't know what is yet in the body, and so the script finds nothing. Just before the body-close, the script comes after what was loaded, and has access to it.

Comment: I just changed jquery source to: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" and it works

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam [Don’t Use jquery-latest.js](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/)

Comment: @GSerg I have followed thread marked as duplicate by you. What is the reason for not using it?

Comment: Also wrapped jquery code inside $(function(){})

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Click the link to read why. The point was to use `$(function(){})`, not a specific jQuery version.

Comment: Then re-open this question

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam it's never a good idea to make production apps that depend on code that is a work-in-progress. Latest implies that it is the cutting-edge, experimental version. But as that article says - they have since frozen it at 1.11.1 anyway, to sidetrack this issue

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Why do you want this question reopened? It is not relevant what jquery version the previous OP used, it's only relevant the solution is to [use `.ready`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602361/11683) in one form or another.

Comment: @GSerg Not working in $(document).ready(function() {}); block.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam The please edit your question with your current actual code where you are using `.ready`, then we shall reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="links" href="http://www.amazon.com" >Amazon</a>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#links').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
</script>
```

The id `links` must exists before referring it.

You can also use the [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function of jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#links').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `anchor` is not ready yet, because your **DOM** is not ready yet,

you should wrap your `script` in **document ready** function, then it will work.

```js
$(function(){
$('#links').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <a id="links" href="http://www.amazon.com" >Amazon</a>
```