# Handle onclick event for partial view buttons

Tags: javascript

I have in a page more `partial views` rendered.
This is how the page looks:
[image]

I need to handle to `onclick` event for the button Create Invoice

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="button-bar col-md-2">
        @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ShowInvoice, "EditLotDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Id = 0, LotId = ViewBag.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
    </div>

    <div class="button-bar col-md-2">
        @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.CreateInvoice, "EditLotDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Id = 0, LotId = ViewBag.Id }, new { @id = "InvoiceDamageButton", @class = "btn btn-success", onclick = "validate" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The buttons are on a `partial view` with name: `LotDamageButtonBarPartial`, which is rendered from another partial view like this:

```
........
tabDamage.SetContent(() =>
    {
        if (ViewBag.CanModify)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("LotDamageButtonBarPartial");
        }
        Html.RenderAction("LotDamageListPartial", new { LotId = ViewBag.Id });
    });
   ........
```

I have tried to handle the onclick event like this in the main page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#InvoiceDamageButton').click(function ()
        { 
            alert("test");
        });
});
```

but it is not working. Can you advise?

Comment: 1. You are using more than just vanilla js. 2. Use dynamic binding [Why is this jQuery click function not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602331/why-is-this-jquery-click-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating `InvoiceDamageButton` button, you are also defining an onclick handler for it here: `onclick = "validate"`.

I don't know the code of `validate()` but it is probably stoping [event propagation](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and the event never triggers your jQuery function.

Check if there's a `e.stopPropagation();` inside function validate, if there is then remove this line. Also, check if `validate()` is returning `false` and if it is, change that too (either don't return anything or return true).