# jquery click function not working even after using $(document).ready(function() {}); and even after using $(function) block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to extract the `id=obj1` from the string `html_doc` and trying to attach an `onclick function` to it

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
function (event) {
    $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest("data/GOG123.json", 
        function (res) {
            var residue=res.residues;

            var html_doc = "<div>" + "<Button id = obj1>" + residue[0].index + "</Button> " + "</div>";
            console.log(html_doc);

            var html_doc2;

            html_doc2= $("html_doc").find("obj1");
            $(document).ready(function(){
                html_doc2.click(function () {
                    alert("Hello!");
                });
            });

            var div1=$("#infoDiv");
            div1.append(html_doc);
        }
    );

});
```

It is not working (i.e not showing an alert message) neither it is throwing any error.

Can someone please help me with the same?

I referred to [Why is this jQuery click function not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602331/why-is-this-jquery-click-function-not-working) but it did not work out for me.

Comment: You need single quote in `"<Button id = 'obj1'>"` and `#` is for id so $("html_doc").find("#obj1");

Comment: please generate snippet here ,for exact solution.Try to put document ready outside  addEventListener block

Comment: try to put lil clear code snippet . bcz while executing its giving  $ajaxUtils is undefined

Comment: Thanks so much but its still not working.

Comment: Alright I'll put the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `.on()` click event.

```
$(document).on("click", "#obj1", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ajax in either function or inside document ready.without extracting id you can do same thing if you know id.

```js
var html_doc = "<div>" + "<Button id = obj1> Click" + "</Button> " + "</div>";//instead of click put ur code
var div1 = $("#infoDiv");
div1.append(html_doc);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#obj1").click(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=infoDiv>This is div info</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. The problem is solved