# Jquery click function not working with $(document).ready

Tags: jquery

I know my question has been asked many times but when trying the most common solution that I've seen from multiple stackoverflow answers, I couldn't get it to work. As an example: [Why is this jQuery click function not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602331/why-is-this-jquery-click-function-not-working). Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental?

Can someone explain why given the following html,

```
<button id="test1">Create</button>
```

The following javascript does not fire the button click,
`option1`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test1").click(function(){
      console.log("TEST1");
    });
  });
```

but the javascript below does?
`option2`

```
$(document).on("click","#test1",function(){
    console.log("TEST123")
  })
```

If anything I thought `option1` would work because it waits for the document to be ready, but instead `option1` doesn't and `option2` does. Why is that the case? Thank you.

Comment: It should work. You only need the second version if you're adding the button dynamically after the document is loaded.

Comment: When you say dynamically do you mean base on a condition for the button to appear?

Comment: I mean using JavaScript to add the button to DOM, rather than having it statically in the HTML.

Comment: Does it count if I have the button inside a ```div``` and that ```div``` has an ```id```, and the javascript uses that ```id``` to determine whether the ```div``` appears or not?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter whether it appears, just whether it's in the DOM.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons with the same ID? IDs have to be unique, and the selector will only select the first one.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange because the button is definitely in the DOM and no I don't have multiple elements using the same ```id```. It's only for the button.

Comment: What happens if you put `console.log($("#test1").length)` right before the `.click()` function.

Comment: Maybe playing with one of these fiddles will help?  http://jsfiddle.net/deshpandeakhil/4kGaR/  http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/PT7x9/

Comment: It shows up as 1

Comment: ```jsfiddle``` doesn't seem to like ```option2``` but likes ```option1```. I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

These use the JQuery library. Are you sure you have JQuery loaded on your page?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What error is your console giving, if any?

Both options work for me.

Option1 = https://jsfiddle.net/wt78mqz3/1/

Option2 = https://jsfiddle.net/wt78mqz3/2/

Answer (score 0):

After the document is loaded you want to use, if and only if you are adding the button dynamically to the page using JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click","#test1",function(){
    console.log("TEST123")
})
```